# AJAX updates from SQL Server Database: Incorrect values returned

Tags: sql-server, ajax, sqldatareader

I have an ASP.NET reporting interface that displays several values that are returned from a SQL Server backend. Once logged in, the browser page is never reloaded, but several screen areas are updated on a timer through AJAX calls.

My problem is that the screen areas are intermittently displaying values that are coming from previous AJAX calls. I have thoroughly and intensively investigated the problem for a number of days and I haven't been able to specifically pinpoint what is causing it, or how to completely overcome it. Currently the incorrect values are very infrequent (3 in 50,000, say), but I should be getting none whatsoever! These are some details about the setup:

- the screen refresh timer runs every 30 seconds to update all screen areas
- there is a 1.5 second lag between the screen area updates
- the values used to decide which SQL stored proc to run to get the correct values from the database for each screen area are being passed in to the ASP.NET interface correctly - I know with 100% certainty which stored proc to run
- the stored proc returns its values to a SQLDataReader
- it is the reader that is sometimes yielding values that seem to be "buffered" from previous AJAX interactions, i.e. I am running the correct stored proc with the correct variables, but the values returned are not what I get if I ran that precise same command in a SQL query interface - they are results from a previous call
- the SQL connection, command and reader are all created and instantiated afresh for each interaction and disposed of correctly after use through the IDisposable interface
- I have swapped the reader for a dataset, with no difference in results
- my AJAX calls are synchronous (async=false), so they should each complete before the next one is run, but I also have the 1.5 sec delay between screen area updates and 30 secs between cycles, so they shouldn't run into each other in any event.

What is frustrating is that the reader is running a SQL statement without throwing an exception, but seemingly returning results from a previous interaction - and then only very seldom, but one incorrect result is one too many.

I am not using ASP.NET state management at all - switched off in web.config.

What am I missing?

Comment: After much searching we have established that the issue is related to this problem with ADO.NET dataproviders: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/74a5db87-c63f-4386-b317-e848dedb2cd9). It is a combination of pooling and threads (in our case not managed by us, but by IIS), which causes this very, very, very seriously flawed result. We're still working on an acceptable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Profile the sql statements that are arriving at sql server with sql server profile. You can narrow the potential locations of the bug that way. next, start the fiddler http debugger and verify the http requests. and let us know what you found!

Answer (score 0):

> it is the reader that is sometimes
>   yielding values that seem to be
>   "buffered" from previous AJAX
>   interactions, i.e. I am running the
>   correct stored proc with the correct
>   variables, but the values returned are
>   not what I get if I ran that precise
>   same command in a SQL query interface
>   - they are results from a previous call the SQL connection, command and
>   reader are all created and
>   instantiated afresh for each
>   interaction and disposed of correctly
>   after use through the IDisposable
>   interface I have swapped the reader
>   for a dataset, with no difference in
>   results

It would help to show us your code here.  If the data objects contain the wrong values, you have to demonstrate with certainty that the correct SPs are being run on the back end and, if applicable, that the correct parameters are being passed to the back end. You should be able to step through the call in the Visual Studio debugger.